# Unclear "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error

Tags: ios, swift

I came back to my old XCode project after a few months and now I have lots of errors where I had none before, which I'm assuming has to do with an updated syntax.

Why am I seeing:

> **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context**

for this block

```
@IBAction func submitUrl(sender: UIButton) {
    var app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    //Error occurs in below declaration of studentDict
    var studentDict = ["latitude": self.latitude, "longitude": self.longitude, "firstName": app.firstName, "lastName": app.lastName, "mediaURL": urlField.text]
    var studentInfo = StudentInformation(data: studentDict as! [String : AnyObject])
    ParseClient.sharedInstance().postStudent(studentInfo, mapString: self.mapString){(success,data) in
        if(success){
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            Shared.showError(self,errorString: data["ErrorString"] as! String)
        }

    }
}
```

I tried `studentDict:NSArray` and `studentDict:Dictionary` because I thought it just couldn't interpret the stuff in `studentDict` properly, but that did not help. What exactly is the error telling me that I'm missing?

Comment: The Swift language underwent some rather major changes in becomming version 2.

Comment: Try studentDict: [String: AnyObject] = ...

Comment: Is there an optional in the values that you init the dictionary with?

Comment: Are you still facing this? I think this has been resolved in swift version 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if somebody still faces this kind of issue:

> Golden rule of swift - **You have to be clear about the type of your
>   objects.**

When you declare method which expects Array as parameter (**without specifying the type of objects with in the array** i.e. `[String]` or `[MyModelObject]` or `[SKProduct]`) and would like to use the parameter in the definition, you have two choices:

- Either you specify the type of the object when try to use / access it. Below as example:

  `for object in objects as! [SKProduct] {
      self.productsToPurchase.addObject(object)
  }`

Here, `objects` is an array defined like this: `var objects:NSArray?`

- Or **revise the definition** of your method and specify the type of objects. Below as example:

  `func getMeProducts(products: [SKProduct]) {
      NSLog("Okay! Ready for purchase")
  }`

In the latter case, the compiler won't allow you to send generic Array object. By generic I mean where you don't specify the type of objects array is holding on.

I hope this makes sense. If not, *read the Golden rule again* :)

Answer (score 3):

One or more of the values that you init with is probably optional and therefore can be nil. That's why you receive this error

```
var studentDict:[String:AnyObject?] = ["latitude": self.latitude, "longitude": self.longitude, "firstName": app.firstName, "lastName": app.lastName, "mediaURL": urlField.text]
```